# Rails mongoid has_one queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, has-one

In User model there is has_one relation to Professional. In the professional model I have one Array field named industries.

I need to take all values where professional industries in "IT"

I tried `User.where(:"professional.industries".in => ["IT"])`

But Its not working. Any sugestions..??

Comment: that's the point with nosql. Your relation could only work if models were embedded.

Comment: @apneadiving : Oh. is it.? It won't work for has_many.! Only for embbeds.. OKie.. Got it.. Thanks man...

Answer (score 0):

In order for your query to work you should use

```
    class User
      embeds_one :professional
    end
```

If you are sure that Professional should be a separate collection you could use something like:

```
    uids  = Professional.where(:"industries".in => ["IT"]).distinct(:user_id)
    users = User.where(:_id.in => uids)
```

Comment: I have already used this logic, I was just checking If we can use One Query for this purpose. Anyway  thanks for the reply